# How to setup routes for authentication

Tags: angular

If currentUser in AppComponent is not null the app goes to the `ShellComponent`. If currentUser is null the app goes to the `LoginComponent`. I'm able to route from LoginComponent to ShellComponent and I'm also able to route between those children and back to the `LoginComponent`. What's not working is routing to the ForgotPasswordComponent from LoginComponent. My routing setup is inspired from this [video](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaIAHOSKHCQ&t=),

When I try to navigate to ForgotPasswordComponent the URI changes to `localhost:4200/forgot-password,` but it still shows the `LoginComponent`. There's no errors in the console.

The reason why the setup look as it does is because I dont want any element in ShellComponent, e.g. `<div class="wrapper">`, `<app-sidebar>`, etc to be present in LoginComponent nor ForgotPasswordComponent nor any other component outside the ShellComponent.

What's going on here?
What have to be done in order for my routes to work?

**Route**

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: '', component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'schedule', component: ScheduleComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'division', component: DivisionComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'result', component: ResultComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'statistics', component: StatisticsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'rules', component: RulesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent }     
])
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- If user is already logged in -->
<router-outlet *ngIf="currentUser"></router-outlet>

<!-- If user is logged out -->
<app-login *ngIf="!currentUser"></app-login>
```

**shell.component.html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  <div class="main-panel">
   <app-navbar></app-navbar>
   <div class="content">
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
   <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In general there should be a rout to login, without AuthGuard, and in authguard check if the user is not logged in route to login with returnUrl and when login is done if the was a returnUrl, navigate to that

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only use `router-outlet` within app-html, then it should work.

**app.component.html**

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

You can also use `canActivateChild` instead of using `canActivate` on every subroute of `ShellComponent`. `canActivateChild` can be used on a parent and will effect also on its childs, see https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild